# How to default toggle to open using css/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code that collapses/expands an html area on click.  By default it's closed...How can I set the default to either open or closed.

[http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes you should make in order to start with the list expanded. First, remove the line `$(".toggle_container").hide();`. Second, add the class "active" to the line `<div class="trigger"><a>Click here</a>` so it becomes `<div class="trigger active"><a>Click here</a>`.

Comment: Ok, cool. But if I want it closed on default?  Removing .hide() and setting the <div class="trigger"> doesn't close it be default.  How can I set it to either open or closed on default?

class="trigger

Comment: The .hide() will close the list (make it look closed but really just not display it). Adding and removing the "active" class just either makes the plus or minus image show up. So if you want it open when the page loads, remove the .hide() and add the "active" class. If you want it hidden when the page loads, keep the hide() and remove the "active" class. If I misunderstood your question just let me know.

Comment: Sure, sure, I'm with you but how do I display two lists, one list open and then another list below it as closed such as, http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/7/ (The first list is fine...open on default...but I want the second list closed on default?  Do I need two classes to do this (toggle_container_open and toggle_container_closed) to set default behavior (i.e. open or closed)?

Comment: I've forked your fiddle and updated the latest code at http://jsfiddle.net/eEhnN/. Is this what you're looking for (one list open and the other closed when the page loads)? Basically, in addition to some minor jQuery, you just need to setup your lists so that they both have the class "trigger", but any list you want to default to open also has the class "active" (e.g. class="trigger active").

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/1/

```
$('div.trigger').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your exact question, here's a stab at it:

If you just take-out this line: `$(".toggle_container").hide();` then the container will "respect all css properties" applied to the element. If in a CSS style-sheet you set the element(s) to be hidden then they will be hidden and visa-versa.

Comment: right but I what about defaulting it to either open or closed, http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/5/

Comment: `.toggle_container { display : none; }` -- This CSS will hide the element when the page loads. I'm not sure what conditions need to be met in your case to hide or show the element.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/VWZTh/

Comment: Right, but what about defaulting to either open or closed, http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/5/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$(".toggle_container").hide();` line below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Remove this line --> $(".toggle_container").hide();
        $("div.trigger").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Set `active` CSS class in trigger, as shown below:

```
<div class="trigger active"><a>Click here</a>
</div>
<div class="toggle_container">
    <div class="block">    
        <ul>
            <li>List item 01</li>
            <li>List item 02</li>
            <li>List item 03</li>
            <li>List item 04</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, yes...but something like this for either open/closed default. http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCXU/5/